# Turn Update/Join into query

Tags: mysql

I have

```
Update2 `Table1` AS T1 Inner Join `Table2` As T2
On T2.`Name` = T1.Name
Set T1.`ParentID` = T2.`ID`
```

I want to check it first, getting brain freeze after long weekend, help appreciated.

I basically want to check first

```
Select FieldA, concat(FieldC,', ',FieldD) `Table1` AS T1 Inner Join `Table2` As T2
on T2.`Name` = T1.Name
Set T1.`ParentID` = T2.`ID`
```

to make sure I'm getting the right results.

Comment: You want to select the results of the future update into a select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An equivalent SELECT could be:

```
SELECT T1.`ParentID` = T2.`ID`
FROM `Table1` AS T1 Inner Join `Table2` AS T2
  ON T2.`Name` = T1.Name
```

[pt-query-digest](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/pt-query-digest.html) is an example of a tool that translates UPDATEs into SELECTs so it can run EXPLAIN.

Comment: Ok thank you that worked. I have an updated question but will post as another thank you!